# Bound for $\left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos kx\right|$.

Tags: real-analysis

It is well known that
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin kx\right| \leq \frac{1}{|\sin \frac{x}{2}|}.$$

I'm wondering, is there a similar well-known bound for $$\left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos kx\right|?$$

Comment: Pardon my indifference but any reference for the first inequality?

Comment: I don't know if it has a name or anything, but it was presented in class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recognize that such sum is the real part of a complex geometric (finite) sum, this yields :
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \cos(kx)= \Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{ikx}\right)= \Re\left(e^{ix} {e^{inx}-1 \over e^{ix}-1}\right)={\sin{nx\over2} \over \sin{x \over 2}} \cos\left({(n+1)x\over2}\right) $$
where the first and last equalities follow from Euler's identity and some algebraic passages.
Hence passing to absolute values gives exactly the same bound.

Comment: A justification or general pointing in the direction of where the equality comes from would probably suit this answer. Say, at least something like 'Using Euler's identity, we have that:'

Comment: since the post starts with a "it is well known that..." I thought that wasnt necessary. By the way, editing.